# Need to find control in an ascx, which is inside an aspx page, which is inside a master page

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2010.

I need to find a control (label, textbox, etc) inside an ascx, which is inside an aspx page, which is inside a master page.

control - ascx - aspx - master.page

I'm trying these commands from my ascx.vb, but no one successfully:

ddlAno = CType(Page.FindControl("myASCX").FindControl("ddlAno"), DropDownList)

ddlAno = CType(Page.Controls(1).FindControl("ddlAno"), DropDownList)

Got nothing as dropdownlist control.

Comment: Where are you invoking the logic to find the control inside the user control? The master page or the content page?

Comment: I'm invoking the logic from the control ascx.vb page.

Comment: Carlos - so you want to find a control inside of another user control from a user control on the same page?

Comment: You trying to access it in another user control? @CarlosHeredia

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create a public property that just returns the control itself.  In this case a label named "Label1".

Mark Up:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Property:

```
public Label Label1Control
{
    get
    {
        return Label1;
    }
}
```

Then you can access it in the usercontrol like so. (This is for a usercontrol in Default.aspx).

```
var label = ((Default) Page).Label1Control;
label.Text = "Hello World";
```

Comment: Where do I have to put Label1? In ascx file?

Comment: Label is in the page (not master page).